# Show: $\mathbb{E}(f|\mathcal{F})=\mathbb{E}(f)$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, conditional-probability

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{F}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be trivial, i.e. $\forall A\in\mathcal{F}: \mathbb{P}(A)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$. Show that $\mathbb{E}(f|\mathcal{F})=\mathbb{E}(f)$.

One criterion to prove that is to show that 
$$
\forall A\in\mathcal{F}: \int_A\mathbb{E}(f)\, d\mathbb{P}=\int_Af\, d\mathbb{P}.
$$

Do not know exactly how to show that in common.

For the special case, that $\mathcal{F}=\left\{\Omega,\emptyset\right\}$ it is
$$
\int_{\emptyset}\mathbb{E}(f)\, d\mathbb{P}=0=\int_{\emptyset}f\, d\mathbb{P},~~~~~\int_{\Omega}\mathbb{E}(f)\, d\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{E}(f)\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=\mathbb{E}(f)=\int_{\Omega}f\, d\mathbb{P}.
$$

But how can I prove that if $\mathcal{F}$ is trivial, but not $\mathcal{F}=\left\{\Omega,\emptyset\right\}$?

Comment: What is your definition of a trivial sigma-algebra?

Comment: Do not know! I thought the definition is: $\forall A\in\mathcal{F}: \mathbb{P}(A)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: For every $A$ in $\mathcal A$ such that $\mathbb P(A)=1$, one has $\displaystyle\int_Af\,\mathrm d\mathbb P=\mathbb E(f)$. For every $A$ in $\mathcal A$ such that $\mathbb P(A)=0$, one has $\displaystyle\int_Af\,\mathrm d\mathbb P=0$.

Comment: Why is $\int_A f\, dP=E(f)$ if $P(A)=1$? Don't see that.

Comment: Because the integral on A is the integral on Omega minus the integral on the complement of A which has measure zero, and because any integral on any set of measure zero is zero.