# Show: The integral over a zero set is zero

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

From [Show: $\mathbb{E}(f|\mathcal{F})=\mathbb{E}(f)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661262/show-mathbbef-mathcalf-mathbbef) was motivated:

Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $A\in\mathfrak{A}$ with $\mu(A)=0$. I would like to show that $\int_A f\, d\mu=0$, where $f$ is any measurable function.

I think I should do that in three steps as usual.

(1) $f$ elementary function, i.e.
$$
f=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\chi_{A_i}, A_i:=\left\{f=\alpha_i\right\}, \Omega=\biguplus_{i=1}^n A_i,\alpha_i\geq 0
$$
then
$$
\int_A f\, d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\mu(A_i\cap A)
$$
and because of $\mu(A\cap A_i\leq\mu(A)=0\implies\mu(A_i\cap A)=0$, so that $\int_A f\, d\mu=0$.

(2) $f$ measurable, $f\geq 0$, then there exists a sequence $(f_n)$ of elementar functions with $f_n\nearrow f$ and by (1) and Beppo Levi
$$
\int_A f\, d\mu=\lim_{n}\underbrace{\int_A f_n\, d\mu}_{=0}=0.
$$

(3) $f$ any measurable function, then $f=f^+-f^-$ and by (2) it is
$$
\int_A f\, d\mu=\underbrace{\int_A f^+\, d\mu}_{=0}-\underbrace{\int_A f^-\, d\mu}_{=0}=0
$$

Can you say me if tha's it?

Miro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's correct. Notice that in the last step we use integrability of $\chi_A |f|$ in order to be allowed to split the integrals.